# Unauthorized error when accessing SharePoint REST API after Azure subscription change

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Since we canceled our Azure Free Trial subscription a couple of days ago and are using our Azure Pass subscription we are sporadically getting the following error when trying to access the SharePoint REST API:

401 Unauthorized

Reason given in HTTP response:

```
"The access token has expired. It's valid from '9/4/2015 3:51:21 PM' and to '9/4/2015 4:56:21 PM'.";category="invalid_client"
```

Sometimes, retrying helps, sometimes we have to `reauthenticate`.

Is this somehow caused by the change of the **Azure** subscription?